# At what stage in Development should a 'Coming Soon' page be displayed, if at all?

Tags: website-design, web-app, landing-page

I have just begun developing a Web application, and have often seen 'Coming Soon' pages displayed on other sites before launch, with options such as signing up for notifications and a possibility of becoming a beta tester, as well as the option to share on social media.

My question is, How early on in development should a 'Coming Soon' page be displayed online?

Comment: Not any earlier than when you are 100% certain that it *is* going to come.

Comment: Thank you! What are some ways of being _sure_ that it will come?

Comment: Having the feature completed would be one such way. (There can still be some time till it is ready for deployment, for instance, while you are waiting for translators to complete their translations.)

Comment: this is not really a UX question at all, as the answer depends on many factors including how secretive the project is, whether premarketing is necessary, whether there is an investor or user audience, competitive risks to disclosure, etc